# I don't understand @Resource mappedName element at all

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

I've read both and I don't understand them, can someone give an example and explain it in plain english please ? mainly what's the difference between it and the "name" element/

From Oracle tutorial

> The mappedName element is a non-portable, implementation-specific name
>   that the resource should be mapped to. Because the name element, when
>   specified or defaulted, is local only to the application, many Java EE
>   servers provide a way of referring to resources across the application
>   server. This is done by setting the mappedName element. Use of the
>   mappedName element is non-portable across Java EE server
>   implementations.

From Oracle Javadocs
mappedName

> public abstract String mappedName
>
> A product specific name that this resource should be mapped to. The
>   name of this resource, as defined by the name element or defaulted, is
>   a name that is local to the application component using the resource.
>   (It's a name in the JNDI java:comp/env namespace.) Many application
>   servers provide a way to map these local names to names of resources
>   known to the application server. This mapped name is often a global
>   JNDI name, but may be a name of any form. Application servers are not
>   required to support any particular form or type of mapped name, nor
>   the ability to use mapped names. The mapped name is product-dependent
>   and often installation-dependent. No use of a mapped name is portable.
>
> Default: ""

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say you have a connection pool (`javax.sql.DataSource`) configured in the application server and placed in JNDI under e.g. `java:datasources/jta/MyDb`.

Say a component (an EJB probably) of your application needs to access a database. The `DataSource` could be injected as:

```
@Resource
private DataSource theDatabase;
```

Your component may be generic, i.e. can be deployed in multiple environments. Or in a single environment there may be many datasources (`java:datasources/jta/MyDb1`, `java:datasources/jta/MyDb2`, ...). How do you map the specific `DataSource` to your component?

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:datasources/jta/MyDb")
private DataSource theDatabase;
```

(Exact details could be missing or be application-server specific, but I hope you get the general point.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what's the difference between mappedName and name, since name does a very similar job to what you just said

Comment: `name` is the JNDI name relative to `java:comp/env` which is *private* to the component. This means the component and only the component can access the resource through JNDI at path `java:comp/env/ResourceName`.