# consuming a weblogic datasource options in a web application

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic12c

I have a web application with plain old JDBC being used .
Using weblogic 12c and Java 1.7

Have configured a Generic datasource in weblogic.

For now I am deploying it as a WAR - in future I would need to deploy it as an EAR.

So here are the three options I tried :
Have configured 4 JNDI names for this datasource : 'abc' 'lmn' 'pqr' 'xyz'

## 1

```
public static DataSource dataSource1 = null;
Context initContext1 = new InitialContext();
dataSource1 = (DataSource)initContext1.lookup("abc");
```

This works.

## 2

```
Defined the datasource in web.xml:

<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>lmn</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In java code:

```
 public static DataSource dataSource2 = null;
 Context initContext2 = new InitialContext();
 dataSource2 = (DataSource)initContext2.lookup("lmn");
```

This also works fine

## 3

```
@Resource(name = "pqr")
public static DataSource dataSource3 = null;

conn = dataSource3.getConnection();
```

This does NOT work .

Not sure what is wrong here ?
also what is the better option to use ?

Will test with an EAR file separately and test a second question around it.

Comment: No one should be running a JDK older than 8 anymore.  I'd recommend that you upgrade immediately.

Comment: ok fair point but can you comment on what is the best option / practice to connect using a datasource ?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not static.  You ought to be using a pool of connections.  I don't use Java EE app servers anymore.  I've been using Spring for 15 years.  I recommend it highly.

Comment: In my case I am forced to use a Java EE app server ( weblogic ) . When you recommend spring I am aware of C3P0 and DBCP connection pools but then again those are in a non managed env Vs using connection pooling and data sources in a 'managed' environment

Comment: I would go with the Hikari connection pool.  It's more performant than the others.  You can deploy Spring as a WAR to a Java EE server without leveraging EJBs.

Comment: Yes have heard a lot of good things about Hikari . Am very curious though when you suggest spring WAR in a Java EE server ( I dont have any need of using EJB in my application ) . Mine is a pure rest service . so even if I use spring I still would need to deploy it to an application server correct ?

Comment: Not if you use Spring Boot.  In that case there's no Java EE app server, just an executable JAR file.  Very nice - you can deploy it anywhere you have a JVM.  Perfect for cloud or static servers.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0):

With

```
@Resource(mappedName="pqr")
```

it works on my weblogic.

See [SO: Mapped name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759244/i-dont-understand-resource-mappedname-element-at-all)

Comment: this still gives me the same Null pointer exception - what version of weblogic are you on ? Mine is 12.1.3.0.0 which I think is EE6 certified

Comment: How do you instantiate the instance which holds this annotated field? You can't just instantiate it yourself, otherwise CDI is not applied. I'm not sure but I think the field should not be defined static.